# Connect radiobutton with textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dynamic created form with a textbox and a radiobutton and i want them to work together.

If I write something in the textbox I want the radiobutton to be unchecked and if the radiobutton is checked I want the textbox to be empty. I've tried a lot of different things and some of them just wont work because of the dynamic created form.

Here is some JavaScript code that doesn't work, but maybe it'll help you to realize what I want to do.

```
function radiobox() {
  if (document.getElementById("AbdominalCircumferencetextbox").text == "") {
      document.getElementById("AbdominalCircumferenceradio").checked = true;
  }
}
```

Edit: Ive solved it by doing this!

```
$(document).on("change", "#AbdominalCircumferencetext", function () {
$("#AbdominalCircumferenceradio").prop('checked', false);
});

$(document).on("change", "#AbdominalCircumferenceradio", function () {
$("#AbdominalCircumferencetext").val("");
});
```

Comment: when is this function called?

Comment: it's called on a onchange event on the textbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned jquery in your tags, a simple way of doing this using jQuery is:

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" checked />
```

with associated JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myTextBox").keyup(function() {
       $("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", $(this).val() == "");
    });
    $("#myCheckbox").change(function() {
       $("#myTextBox").val("");
    });
});
```

Demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rs5EC/1/

Comment: Updated, as I missed a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
function radiobox() {
    el = $('#AbdominalCircumferencetextbox')
    if (el.val() == "") {
        el.prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function radiobox() {
    if (document.getElementById("AbdominalCircumferencetextbox").text == "") {
        jQuery("#AbdominalCircumferenceradio").attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
```

Comment: i tried this now but i did not work :(

    function radiobox() {
    if (document.getElementById("AbdominalCircumferencetextbox").text == "") {
        jQuery("#AbdominalCircumferenceradio").attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    if (document.getElementById("AbdominalCircumferencetextbox").text !== "") {
        jQuery("#AbdominalCircumferenceradio").removeattr('checked', 'checked');
    }
}

Comment: @Zenith Pls do a look at his question

Comment: @Nithesh I have - neither of you are using valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
   $("#radioBtn").change(function () {
        if(document.getElementById("radioBtn").checked == true){
              document.getElementById("txtValue").value = "";
        }
    });

    $("#txtValue").on("mousedown",function(){
           document.getElementById("radioBtn").checked = false;
    });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vMGVf/